# How can i read data from ReferenceInput in React admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When I use the referencinput, it sends a request to the server, is it possible to somehow read what I received from the referencinput server and use these values in the farthest. Thank you for any help!

```
<ReferenceInput
      label="Person"
      source={`${parentSourceWithIndex}.person.id`}
      reference="people"
      resource={resource}
      perPage={INPUT_ITEMS_PER_PAGE}
    >
      <SelectInput
        onChange={(event) => console.log(event)}
        resource={resource}
        optionText="fullName"
        inputType="create"
        fullWidth
      />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

Comment: Do you have a Sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s) with some boilerplate code in there to get started with?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I quickly threw up a simple example. When I select a user from the list of users in the form, the referencesinput sends a request to the server and receives a response in the form of a hash, I want to read this response

Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-nash-uvji1u ?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the first two paragraphs of the `ReferenceInput` documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceInput.html

As well as the linked `useChoicesContext` documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useChoicesContext.html